# Visual Studio 2019: This localhost page can’t be found (HTTP ERROR 404) Error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019

Sorry for this trivial question, but I am completely new to ASP.NET Core environment.

I have got a whole project that has been cloned from a Git repo and into the Visual Studio 2019.

The company I am working for have got its project developed by a third party company.

The founder has his own Azure portal account that has everything related to the project.

The steps that I have taken towards running the project were as follows:

- Installed Visual Studio 2019 and logged in using the boss account that he uses for accessing
  Azure portal.
- Cloned the project from a repo that the boss shared with me.
- Ran the Web.API element of the solution using the following configuration in the
  **launchSettings.json** file:

```
  "xxxxxxx.Web.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44368;http://localhost:5000"
    }
```

The following error keeps showing up:

> This localhost page can’t be found
> No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:44368/api/values
> HTTP ERROR 404

I have tried looking everywhere but to no avail. What could cause this error?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Well, should there be a route for `api/values`?  Where is the code which handles that route and what are you expecting it to return?

Comment: You mean a code like the follwoing which I have found in the **Controllers** folder:   

  `namespace xxxxxxx.Web.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/admin")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins")]
    public class AdminController : xxxxxxxControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserBusiness userBusiness;`


As far as I understand, there should be some code that starts with: 

 `[Route("api/values")]` 
that would handle the route. Is this whar you mean @David?

Comment: Generally, yes.  If you have such a route.  If you don’t then that explains why it’s not found.

Comment: What causes it to be missing? I just cloned the project without changing anything! Any idea?

Comment: Maybe ask whoever wrote or maintains the code?  `api/values` sounds like a default route used in a project template as kind of a "hello world" application.  It's possible that it originally was exactly that and was removed if it's not needed.  Either way, nobody here can know what the code you're talking about is *supposed* to do.  That's really up to you.